# Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET Web API with roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

net web api with asp.net identity this is my code:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public string FullNamme { get; set; }
    public string ProfileType { get; set; }

    public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(GenerateUserIdentity(manager));
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I would like to manage auhtorization according to `public string ProfileType { get; set; }` if it is Client or Professinal...
Something like that `[Authorize(TypeProfile="xxx")]` ...
If it's not possible how can i add simple roles to my code and how can i define default Login page to redirect if user is not Log in .

I hope you can help me..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/31/asp-net-web-api-claims-authorization-with-asp-net-identity-2-1/.

See Method 2. Creating custom Claims Authorization attribute